# No tests found... jest does not find tests

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I faced with a problem while writing a test for my react component.

There is my test
[image]

And there is my console message

[image]

I also tried npm/yarn install, and also looked at similar problems on the Internet but ... nothing. Maybe someone faced with a similar problem

Jest file
[image]

Comment: show your jest file. Probably test pattern is wrong. You can try: `testMatch: ['**/?*.test.ts(x)']`

Comment: just added picture

Comment: Seems your testRegex works only for `__test__` dir in project root. Did you try my pattern?

Comment: yeah, tried run test from __test__ dir and tried your pattern. nothing helped

Comment: I just checked. Empty config like this works: `module.exports = {
  testMatch: ['**/?*.test.ts(x)'],
}`
Maybe jest don't see your config